# XOR'ing two chunks of memory efficiently

Tags: c, buffer, simd

I have two buffers `buf1` and `buf2` of same length `len`. I would like to efficiently obtain the `xor` between these two buffers. I'm running gcc (5.1) on a Linux system.

- The two buffers are page-aligned (with `posix_memalign`, with alignment of `getpagesize()`)
- The result can be stored in `buf1`, since I no longer need its contents after the operation.

I have tried casting the `void*` to `uint64_t*` and perform an `^=` operation, but it still not fast enough for my needs (comparison of data from block devices).

Are there library function -- in the likes of `memcmp` -- that would achieve what I want? Or are there libraries specialized in such tasks?

How complicated would be a homemade implementations, with possibly SIMD instructions? (I'm working on a Haswell-DT G3258, and portability is not an issue for now)

PS: my CPU flags are:

`fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave rdrand lahf_lm abm ida arat pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust erms invpcid xsaveopt`

Comment: Please choose one of C and C++ for this question. If you are working on Linux, could you tell us the content of /proc/cpuinfo so we know what CPU extensions we can use?

Comment: How large are these buffers? Are they inside the L1 cache? If you are reading from a block device, the IO time is likely to be several order of magnitudes larger than the time to xor the data blocks. I don't know what kind of speedup you expect.

Comment: The machine I'm working on is in fact a stripped down Haswell, see the flags (edit done in question). I am typically using 4096 byte buffers, and I read data from SSD disks.

Comment: You should consider that storing the value back inside an already used buffer is a manual optimization to reduce RAM usage, which might possible come at the expense of execution speed, if it gets translated to a read-modify-write. You could try to store the results in a 3rd buffer and see if it helps performance. In order to optimize this code manually, you'll most likely have to watch the disassembly.

Comment: @mamahuhu Consider reading much more than 4096 bytes at once. Round trips to kernel space are quite slow and eat up a lot of time. Are you sure the IO bandwidth is not limiting you?

Comment: @Fuzxxl is correct. If all you're doing is XORing the two buffers together, then your limiting factor is definitely going to be I/O. Even if you had both of them in memory, if the datasets are large enough, then main memory bandwidth would end up limiting your speed. You can certainly implement the XOR using SSE/AVX instructions, but you have a very low computation-to-memory-access ratio, so you will see little (if any) speedup. Your CPU can XOR bytes much faster than the memory hierarchy can keep it fed with new data.

Comment: @JasonR I've actually timed this right now. Block size doesn't make any difference on my system (with an SSD), with the optimal size being between 512 and 8192 bytes (sic!). This is quite surprising to me.

Comment: @JasonR If you are reading the file sequentially, it might help to use `posix_fadvise()` to hint to the kernel what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is one of the buffers fixed (i.e. always the same content) or does it vary?

Comment: @FUZxxl : none of the buffers is fixed.

Comment: @mamahuhu Could you do a test where you compare code that doesn't xor the buffers at all with code that uses the naïve approach to buffer xoring so we can see the amount of possible optimization? Also, have you tried to increase the buffer size?

Comment: @ FUZxxl Sorry for the lack of updates. And to answer your request, the difference is indeed negligible. The answer referenced by Olaf fits my question. Thanks to all.